# running python script as service and calling functions from another program

Tags: python, services

I have a python script to control some LEDS. In a compiled c++ program I have been calling python scripts like so in various places:

```
system("python /home/pi/leds_flash.py")

system("python /home/pi/leds_sleep.py)
```

Each of those function controls led lights accordingly and `exits()`. It's working great, but I really need my python script to keep state.

I am assuming that the best way to set things up is to create an instance of an LED controller script that remains running in the background on which I could invoke functions or send messages.

I've briefly been looking into how to run a [script as a servic](http://www.diegoacuna.me/how-to-run-a-script-as-a-service-in-raspberry-pi-raspbian-jessie/)e, but still unsure how to invoke functions on this service or if this is even the best way to accomplish what I am after.

I'm a newb to raspberry pi and python so appreciate any guidance on this.

Comment: Would you please elaborate just a bit on what "state(s)" you need to keep track of?

Comment: I want to keep the state of the led lights - knowing the current status of any animation that they might be playing.  Additionally, I have to run some initialization before controlling the light strips (neo-pixels) and my thinking is that it would be more performant to create that 1x and keep it in memory vs creating/destroying it over and over.

Comment: Can't you read the state of the GPIO pin to get state?

Comment: No, not easily. It's not really a single high/low setting that is controlling the LEDS. I'm using https://github.com/jgarff/rpi_ws281x

Comment: In general it is possible to run programs as service with systemd and you have very much possibilities to manage it, e.g. by setting the environment and rights or use dependencies to other services (start before/after). But it makes less sense to speculate if we do not have a program. I suggest that you make a simple systemd Unit file just only for starting your program and improve it step by step until it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem, though I don't know if there is a better or more efficient way to accomplish this. I created a [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) app to control the LEDs and have the C++ app making GET requests for on/off state.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.